How to find out when GA is actually counting realtime users?
As mentioned already in this post, in GA realtime users sometimes displays constantly surging peaks every 5 minutes. This definitely doesn't apply to "reality".
As the post hasn't been answered I wonder how I can investigate any further.
My aim is to find out when GA is actually adding a count to one specific time slot in realtime users and which event is responsible for this.
I debugged the received events in tagassistant. But this only shows incoming events like page_view, etc. but does not provide information about when GA is actually adding a count to the time slot.
Unfortunately setting debug_mode in gtag config (gtag('config', 'G-123456789', { 'debug_mode':true });) didn't work at all (nothing shows up in GA DebugView).
Is there any way to receive an gtag event when GA is actually counting a user in realtime? Are there any other methods to debug this issue?

